# call __readfsword() and __readgsword() based on visual studio program configuration

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

Hi I am new to Visual Studio,

I want to use windows intrinsic `__readfsword()` and `__readgsword()` but I can only use `__readfsword()` for x86 and `__readgsword()` for 64 bit app. I am building my program for both x86 and 64 bit app.

If I change my app configuration to x86 then it throws error that `__readgsword()` is invalid identifier but it identifies `__readfsword()` and reverse for 64 bit.

I want to build my app without making changes to the app, but because of this error I have to change the code everytime I change the configuration. Is there a solution in visual studio where I can build without changing the code and it takes these functions based on configuration?

Comment: Use conditional compilation `#ifdef` for the build type round the function calls

Comment: #ifdef _WIN32
    int val = __readfsword(4)
#else
    int val = __readgsword(4)
#endif

this still throws error that either __readfsword() or __readgsword() is invalid indentifier. If I change configuration it reverse the error for other function

Comment: `_WIN32` is defined for any architecture targeting the Win32 subsystem. You need to pick a [predefined macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros) that refers to the target architecture, such as `_M_X64` and `_M_IX86`.

Comment: _M_X64 worked in my case

#ifdef _M_X64
#define fun(offset) __readgsdword(offset)
#else
#define fun(offset) __readfsdword(offset)
#endif

this doesn't throw compilation error

Comment: That should work for you. However, `_M_X64` is also set for `_M_ARM64EC` targets, so you may want to filter that out. Also, you should avoid introducing (function-like) macros. Just declare a function and keep the conditions local to that function. Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/T66sjccPa) should do. This fails to compile when discovering unsupported CPU architectures, guarding against future changes to the compilation environment.

Comment: [Code](https://godbolt.org/z/4YcaKaMe9) with typo fixed (`_M_IX86` vs. `_M_X86`).

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved by application of [conditional compilation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional). It is a language feature of C and C++ that allows including or excluding regions of code from being compiled based on compile-time predicates.

MSVC supplies several [predefined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros) that can be used to derive predicates. There are many to choose from, and the challenge is to pick the most appropriate one(s).

The knee-jerk reaction here is to pick `_WIN32` vs. `_WIN64`. This would be inappropriate for two reasons:

- Even though they look very similar, `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` refer to unrelated concepts: `_WIN32` describes the API being used (that is, the API of the Win32 subsystem), whereas `_WIN64` is set when targeting a 64-bit version of Windows<sup>1</sup>.
- More importantly, the code in question attempts to use CPU instructions that are only available on a specific (family of) CPU architectures.

The correct predefined macros to use are thus those that describe the target architecture, commonly having the `_M`-prefix (short for "machine"), i.e., `_M_X64`<sup>2</sup> and `_M_IX86`.

With the foundational principles covered, here's a possible implementation:

```cpp
#include <intrin.h>

unsigned short read_word(unsigned long offset) {
    #if defined(_M_X64) && !defined(_M_ARM64EC)
        return __readgsword(offset);
    #elif defined(_M_IX86)
        return __readfsword(offset);
    #else
        #error "Unsupported architecture"
    #endif
}
```

This has the compiler emit the appropriate code based on the (compiler-supplied) target architecture macros. If none of the predicates match, compilation will stop when the compiler encounters the [`#error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/error) directive.

All conditionals are evaluated strictly at compile-time, and the object code generated is branch-free. The `#error` case is handled at compile-time as well, either by continuing or terminating compilation.

---

<sup>1</sup> *A consequence of this is that 64-bit application projects usually have both `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` defined, and `#if defined(_WIN32)` does not imply targeting a 32-bit version of Windows.*

<sup>2</sup> *`_M_X64` is also set for [`_M_ARM64EC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/arm64ec) targets, where "EC" is short for "Emulation Compatible." I don't know whether intrinsics are part of that emulation, so the conditional excludes `_M_ARM64EC`.*